# UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u010d'

Tags: python

I am using a Python script to open a .csv file and import the data to a database.  There are several latin characters that were causing errors, so I have tried to encode those with UTF-8 and use the errors='replace'  specification to replace those troublesome characters with a question mark.  However, even after doing this I have been receiving the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u010d' in position 2: character maps to <undefined>
```

I am using Python 3.7.4. Here is my current code:

```
import csv
import cx_Oracle
import io

localfile = 'C:/User/Documents/Upload/data.csv'
connection = cx_Oracle.connect()

with io.open(localfile, 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='replace') as csvfile:
        for row in reader:
                connection.execute("INSERT INTO database.my_table (Column_1, Column_2, Column_3) values (:1, :2, :3)", [
                    row[0], row[1], row[2]])
                    connection.execute('commit')
            connection.execute('commit')
```

EDIT:

Here is the full Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\User\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.8.30787\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py", line 43, in <module>
    main(ptvsdArgs)
  File "c:\User\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.8.30787\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 432, in main
    run()
  File "c:\User\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.8.30787\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 316, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name='__main__')
  File "C:\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "C:\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\User\Documents\Python_Projects\python_sftp_remote_server_edition.py", line 116, in <module>
    insert(localfile, c)
  File "c:\User\Documents\Python_Projects\python_sftp_remote_server_edition.py", line 28, in insert
    row[0], row[1], row[2]])
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u010d' in position 2: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: `errors` governs how invalid UTF-8 is handled. "\u010d" was successfully decoded to a Unicode character so clearly it was not invalid. Please [edit] to show the full traceback; but I'm guessing your database connection is not properly set up to receive Unicode.

Comment: Another crude workaroud would be to open with `encoding='ascii'` but the whole `errors='replace'` strategy is highly dubious in the first place. Ideally you should not wreck the data you handle.

Comment: @tripleee I have updated the question to show the full traceback.  You make a good point regarding the database setup--I hadn't thought about that.  I'll check and make sure that's not an issue.  Thanks!

Comment: There is some useful background about character sets in https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/globalization.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your help.  While none of the answers directly fixed the problem, I was able to use them to research a bit more and ultimately find a solution that allowed the script to run without errors and insert the data into my Oracle database.  Just wanted to post my (working) code below in case anyone else runs into the same difficulties.

```
import csv
import cx_Oracle
import io

localfile = 'C:/User/Documents/Upload/data.csv'
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(conn_str, encoding="utf-8")

with io.open(localfile, 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='backslashreplace') as csvfile:
        for row in reader:
                connection.execute("INSERT INTO database.my_table (Column_1, Column_2, Column_3) values (:1, :2, :3)", [
                    row[0], row[1], row[2]])
                    connection.execute('commit')
            connection.execute('commit')
```

Answer (score 1):

As the traceback reveals, the database expects to receive input in Windows codepage 1252. You can try to convert into this encoding with `errors='replace'` and then convert back:

```
item = item.encode('cp1252', errors='replace').decode('cp1252')
```

Just to spell this out, we are converting Unicode strings back to Unicode via CP1252 and replacing any character which cannot be round-tripped - only to then pass the result to an interface which will convert this to CP1252 again. This is arguably not at all elegant.

A much better strategy is to switch to a database which can properly handle Unicode. With `errors='replace'` you are basically asking the computer to corrupt any data which the limited legacy target character encoding cannot handle.

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly encoding and decoding your cell values. I created a sample .csv file in French and this code worked out for me:

```
import csv
import cx_Oracle
import io

localfile = 'C:/User/Documents/Upload/data.csv'
connection = cx_Oracle.connect()

with io.open(localfile, 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='replace') as csvfile:
        for row in reader:
                connection.execute("INSERT INTO database.my_table (Column_1, Column_2, Column_3) values (:1, :2, :3)", [
                    str(row[0]).encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8'), str(row[1]).encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8'), str(row[2]).encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')])
                    connection.execute('commit')
            connection.execute('commit')
```